# How to Debug Localhost - This Site Can't Be Reached

Tags: linux, macos, apache, lamp

I setup LAMP on my MacOS computer using the https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-upgrade-homebrew tutorial series.

It works for a month or two and then suddenly (without any changes made to config) it will stop working.

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The last time this happened I gave up and re-installed from scratch. I don't want to have to do this each time it stops working.

Here is what I've tried so far this time:

```
jackrobson$ ps -aef | grep httpd
  501 84635   459   0  5:03pm ttys000    0:00.00 grep httpd
jackrobson$ sudo apachectl -k restart
jackrobson$ tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log
[Sun Sep 16 14:43:22.548017 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 74] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Sun Sep 16 14:43:22.635379 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 74] AH00163: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) PHP/7.0.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 16 14:43:22.635437 2018] [core:notice] [pid 74] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

My /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/jackrobson/Projects"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see, the last error was over two weeks ago. No errors today even though I'm getting the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Got it working, these are the commands that I did before it worked:

```
jackrobson$ sudo apachectl stop
jackrobson$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
jackrobson$ brew services restart httpd
==> Successfully started `httpd` (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
```